# How to get name from Identity

Tags: azure-active-directory

We are using Azure AD OWIN to authenticate the user in a MVC application.

When I need to get the user's name or even preferred_username, I look at these properties. But the name is null.

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name = null

User.Identity.Name = null
```

But the Claims property under Identity contain the values that I need.

How can I get the Claims properties values under Identity, such as "name" or "preferred_username"?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the [Azure AD attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes#:%7E:text=Azure%20AD%20user%20resource%20type%20%20%20,%20Persisted%2C%20Output%20%2016%20more%20rows%20)? "displayName" might work. Please let me know if this works.

Best,
James